# Android can't establish FTP connection over wifi

Tags: android, ftp

My code connects to an FTP server. It does so fine while I'm at home using wifi. It also does so fine using data anywhere(4g). It doesn't connect, however, when I'm using my schools wifi. It eventually just times out. It's strange, because I could previously connect using FTP with my school's wifi.

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    System.out.println("DoInBackground");
            try {
        Client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        System.out.println("Connecting");
        Client.connect(hostname, port);
        System.out.println("Connected");
```

It prints out DoInBackground and Connecting, but never reaches Connected. Any ideas as to why this could be happening? Also, I wasn't sure where to put the enterLocalPassiveMode, so I tried it both before and after and both had the same result.

Comment: Does your school's network block the FTP port? Can you access your FTP server with another device? It sounds like this is an issue with the network, not your code.

Comment: Nathan Walters - If it is an issue with the network, how would I get around this? Users need to be able to access the files I have stored on the server from anywhere wifi or data. Should I do it another way as opposed to FTP? It has to be the FTP that's the problem because I can access the internet from the browser and other apps like Instagram or Reddit.

Comment: You could use something else, although it probably wouldn't be as simple as FTP would be. I can't personally recommend any methods because I don't have much experience in this area. My apologies.